# Estou desenvolvendo um quiz e não consigo mudar de tela. O que ha de errado com meu código?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

public void botaoClicar(View view) {

```
    Button botaoResposta = (Button) view;

    if (botaoResposta.equals(respostaCorreta)) {
        acertos = acertos + 1;
        pontos = pontos + 10;

        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Questao.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "ESPETACULAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "QUE PENA,VOCÊ ERROU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        acertos = erros + 1;
        pontos = pontos + 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: poderia dar mais detalhes ? qual é o erro/problema que você esta enfrentando ?

Comment: Quando testo o código no emulador o objetivo e que troque de tela ao clicar no botao de alguma alternativa,  mas so exibe a mensagem "QUE PENA VOCÊ ERROU" e não muda de tela.

Comment: Então significa que o if esta sempre dando false. Este respostaCorreta esta com o objeto botão da resposta correta ?
Provavelmente o erro esteja ai

Comment: Obrigada. Vou verificar.